# Would the following question be a better fit here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5814/help-in-setting-up-and-solving-a-transportation-traffic-problem) on the stats stackexchange. is it a better fit here?

Comment: I would say it is a better fit _there_. Of course, there might be someone here who could just answer it for you :-)

Comment: Also, support is the wrong tag to be using.

Answer (score 10):

I think that it's actually more of a stats problem (and you call it a stats project yourself), so it looks to be good where it is. You could say it's linear algebra-related too, and cross-post it at math.stackexchange, but I would probably do that only if I didn't get satisfactory answers on stats.stackexchange after certain amount of time.

Comment: I think statisticians can handle linear algebra issues that arise in statistics questions.